# How best to share data between layout and content areas in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Long time Web Forms developer new to MVC...

I am working on an ecommerce website. In the header common to all pages I need to display some information about the logged-in user, if any, and the contents and total of the shopping cart.

Some of this information is also sometimes required by other non-common parts of the page. For example the logged-in user data is required on many pages, and the shopping cart data is needed on the shopping cart page and throughout the checkout process.

**To minimize database calls I would like to retrieve this information once per page and share it among the different parts of the page.**

I know I can use PageData and `ViewBag` to do this **but would prefer a strongly typed method instead.**

In Web Forms I would have my master page retrieve this information and have it accessible to the other pages through public properties.

How is this best done in MVC, and is better to use Layout Pages or Partials?

**Update**

I did not realise that the view model would be automatically passed to the layout page.

Is it a good method to do the following:

1. Create interface IPageBase with properties and methods required by the Layout page
2. Create a based class PageBase which inherits from IPageBase and implements these properties and methods (ie. retrieves cart and user details from database)
3. Create a view model for each page that inherits from PageBase
4. Pass the page specific view model to the view from the controller and in the Layout page set the model to IPageBase

This all seems to work well enough and suit my needs but is it the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a ViewModel with the desired information and pass that to your Views and Partial Views.

Example:

```
public class CustomerViewModel 
{
    public String UserName { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastLogin { get; set; }
}
```

Not quite sure what information you need so I just used `UserName` and `LastLogin` as an example.

To pass your ViewModel into a View you can use the overloaded [Controller.View](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492930(v=vs.108).aspx) method.

```
return View(customerViewModel);
```

In your View you can use and access the ViewModel properties as described below.

Add the following to the top of your View:

```
@model ProjectName.Web.Models.CustomerViewModel
```

And access the values like this:

```
<h1>Welcome, @Model.UserName</h1>

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use `Partial Views`. Part every section by partial view and manage when they will shown, when not. To work with parts is easy:

```
if(manage_when_it_will_shown)
{
   @Html.Partial("_LogonPartial")
}
```

You also can do database call and show any data.

```
if(manage_when_it_will_occur)
{
    @Html.Action("Action", "Contoller")
}
```